# How to loop through an array and set of dom elements and add the current item of the array to the current dom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

I have a Jquery array holding 4 strings:

> var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

In my markup I have 4 empty div's with other random markup dispersed intermittently between them.

```
<div></div>
<p>Paragraph here</p>
<p>Paragraph here</p>
<div></div>
<h1>heading here</h1>
<p>Paragraph here</p>
<div></div>
<h1>heading here</h1>
<p>Paragraph here</p>
<div></div>
```

I want to loop through the array and also loop through the div's and add the text of the current item in the array to the current div. The end result in my markup should be something like this:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Not a javascript expert as you can probably tell, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. Please tell us about X. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please show us your efforts and how they not worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
$('div').each(function(index){
    this.innerHTML = myArray[index];
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xDtgH/1/)

Comment: OP wants to fill the `<div>`s

Comment: +1, great answer. You should include a link to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) for [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), though.

Comment: @Sergio Perfect, thanks I appreciate it. I'll mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't care for array being empty afterwards you could use:

```
var myArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

$('div').each( function () {
    this.innerHTML = myArray.shift();
});
```